# accept incoming network connections simulator - xcode 13.4.1

Tags: firewall, xcode13, macos-monterey

Does anyone know how to rid of this message?

It is happening every time I build a project using the simulator with the following versions.

- xCode 13.4.1
- mac Monterey  12.4.

I didn't see this behavior in Xcode previous versions.

[image]

The issue seems to be because it is adding a new application every time I build the project into the firewall app list. (image below)
Any tips on how to fix this?

[image]